# UITable view Swipe to deleted jumps and leaves empty space between cell and custom footer View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delete-row

I have a tableview with a custom footer view. When I try to delete the cell it jumps and leaves empty white space between the footer. Here is the code I used.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        switch editingStyle {
            case .delete :
            self.items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            CATransaction.begin()
            CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
                tableView.beginUpdates()
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
                tableView.endUpdates()
            })
            tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
            CATransaction.commit()
            footerView.label.text = "text"
                
            default :
                return
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try adding `tableView.reloadData()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just remove the designated item from your data source and not interfere with the default animation, something like the one below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    switch editingStyle {
        case .delete :
        self.items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        // unless intended, you can avoid this letting the user to delete more items one afte the other
        tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
        footerView.label.text = "text"
            
        default :
            return
    }
}
```

Comment: this post fixed it  https://medium.com/compass-true-north/solved-uitableview-jumps-on-cell-deletion-9a43fdec8de0